# How to inject some HTML code above admin_menu in WordPress Admin?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, admin

I'm trying to add a logo image before the #adminmenu div in WordPress but I don't want to do that with jQuery / CSS techniques of code injecting. So, for that, I need a hook to output the image function above the admin_menu.

`add_action('admin_menu','function');` won't let me do this apparently.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/menu-header.php#L211), the closest you'll get is injecting something below the menu items with the `adminmenu` hook. So I guess some JS to prepend the item will be necessary.

```
add_action( 'adminmenu', 'se26675378_adminmenu' );
function se26675378_adminmenu(){
    echo 'lorem ipsum';
}
```

Comment: Thanks diggy, made the logo show as a list item, will be now trying a JS alternative to place it as the first list element.